# How to acces and commit to remote branch on github

Tags: git, github, remote-branch

I wanted to work on remote github repository from multiple machines, on my laptop it works as intended, however on my PC i can't connect my local branch to remote branch. Maybe they are connected but, when i try to commit message pops up saying that there is nothing to commit even though i made some changes? I did git clone of remote repository, then i did git fetch, then i did git checkout myRemoteRepositoryName.

Message when i try to commit:

Your branch is up to date with 'origin/myBranch'.

My question is how do I contribute to my remote branch from another PC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

type `git status`
if it shows a ton of red, that means nothing is staged. Type in `git add` then the directory you want to stage. Once you have some content staged then type:

```
git commit -m "message goes here"
```

then you will commit to your local branch, now you can push your changes with:

```
git push origin myBranch
```

Comment: `nothing is staged` - Do you mean there is something unstaged/deleted?

Comment: Nope, when you make changes with git you have to first stage them, then commit them. after that you can push that branch to it's remote counterpart. @dan1st

Comment: There could also be something that is staged if there is a bunch of red stuff. I do only think the *nothing* is not accurate.

Comment: It makes more sense in the context of the question, as OP has nothing staged.

Comment: git status

On branch mybranch
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/mybranch'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean

Comment: this is the message that i get, but could there be problem with my credentials? i did git config username and email, but nowhere was i asked for password

Comment: Did you save the file in your editor? Are you sure you are editing the files in the repo?

Comment: yeap this was it, i had auto save on laptop but not on pc, i feel dumb now, thanks guys